# Logstash shuts down during clustering

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elk

Im having three 7.4.2 ELK nodes.I have configured clustering in first  elasticsearch/logstash/kibana node and restarted ELK in that node. It wass successful. But once I have configured clustering in second ELK node, first node logstash stopped automatically with below error

```
An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::
    HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError: Could not reach host Manticore::SocketException:
    Connection refused (Connection refused)>, :backtrace=>["/opt///logstash/vendor
    /bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/
    elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:293:in perform_request_to_url'", "/opt/****/****/logstash /vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs /elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:278:in block in perform_request'", "/opt///
    logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/
    logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:373:in with_connection'", " /opt/****/****/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib /logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:277:in perform_request'",
    "/opt///logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-
    java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:285:in block in Pool'", "/opt/****/****/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0- java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:162:in get'", "/opt///logstash/
    ndor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/
    outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:378:in get_xpack_info'", "/opt/****/****/logstash/ vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/ outputs/elasticsearch/ilm.rb:57:in ilm_ready?'", "/opt///logstash/vendor/bundle
    /jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/
    ilm.rb:28:in ilm_in_use?'", "/opt/****/****/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/ logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:52:in block in setup_after_successful_connection'"]}
```

There is a FATAL error in logs as below
[2020-10-12T17:52:25,998][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][events] Failed to install template. {:message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://**.**.**.**:9200/][Manticore::SocketException] Connection refused (Connection refused)", :class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError", :backtrace=>["logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:293:in perform_request_to_url'", "logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:278:in block in perform_request'", "logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:373:in with_connection'", logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:277:in perform_request'", "logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:285:in block in Pool'", "logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:162:in get'", "logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:378:in get_xpack_info'", "logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/ilm.rb:57:in ilm_ready?'", "logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/ilm.rb:28:in ilm_in_use?'", "logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb:14:in install_template'",
logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:130:in install_template'", "logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:51:in block in setup_after_successful_connection'"]}
Any idea? Does it have something to do with ilm_enabled?
I have made clustering changes in elasticsearch as below.

```
cluster.name: "elasticsearch"
    node.name: "node-2"
    node.data: true
    path.logs: "/var/opt/logs/elasticsearch/"
    path.data: "/var/lib/elasticsearch"
    network.host: "**.**.**.**"
    http.port: 9200
    discovery.seed_hosts:
    - "**.**.**.**"
    - "**.**.**.**"
    cluster.initial_master_nodes:
    - "node-1"
    - "node-2"
```

And Im using elasticsearch output plugin , where I added clustering nodes as below.

```
elasticsearch 
            { 
       hosts => ["**.**.**.**:9200","**.**.**.**:9200"]
               document_id => "%{authsid}"
               index =>  "dashboard_write"
               script => "ctx._source.loginCount= params.event.get('loginCount');
                       ctx._source.contractName= params.event.get('contractName');
                        ctx._source.userName= params.event.get('userName');
                         ctx._source.sessionID= params.event.get('sessionID');
                         ctx._source.eventID= params.event.get('eventID');"
              doc_as_upsert => "true"
               action => "update"  
              ilm_enabled => false             
        }
```

I have done above changes in first node elasticsearch.yml & logstash output.conf files and restarted first node. It came up successfully. Then I have done same changes in second node and restarted second node, then first node logstash went down automatically

Comment: Can you explain better what you are trying to do? From your errors your logstash instance is not able to communicate with your elasticsearch. What do you mean by _configured clustering_ ? You added another node to your cluster? Update your question with your `elasticsearch.yml` for your nodes and your logstash pipeline.

Comment: are you sure elastics are reachable on port 9200 from logstash machin?

Comment: It may not be reachable as cluster configuration was in progress and getting restarted. But that should not bring down logstash service, which is what I assumed. Logstash should try reaching elasicsearch till its available

Comment: If my answer is usefull, feel free to upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 1):

In my point of view, your logstash configuration doesn't find the index template. You have ilm_settings in elasticsearch output plugin but you didn't specify the index template. So, logstash trying to find wrong end point. Thats why you get an error. Use similar like below,

```
elasticsearch {
    
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "index_name"
    manage_template => true
    template_overwrite => true
    ilm_enabled => false
    template_name => "template_name"
    template => "path_to_template"
    document_id => "document_id" 
    http_compression => true
}
```